# Is there a way for animations to work with ShadowDOM?

Tags: angular, animation, shadow-dom

As the title states, is there a way to use angular animations' built in transitions with view encapsulation set to ShadowDom?
The transition in the following snippet does not work.

```js
 animations: [
    trigger('toggle', [
      state('off', style({
        transform: 'translateX(0)',
        opacity: 0.5
      })),
      state('on', style({
        transform: 'translateX(100%)',
        opacity: 1,
        background: 'green'
      })),
      transition('on <=> off', [
        animate('0.5s')
      ]),
    ])],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
```

Comment: I tried other ways to add my broken sidebar animation after applying view encapsulation shadow dom. Apparently -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; helped me restore my closing sidebar animation

Comment: i tried but even if i add CSS attributes, it never works. Do you have any updated answers?